# How to convert a date to JSON format using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I convert a date to JSON format using JavaScript or jQuery?

For example: *28/08/2013* or *Wed Aug 28 2013 12:09:29 GMT+0530* to:

> Date(928129800000+0530)

Comment: Duplicate of this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date

Comment: @ManuM: No, that's the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I convert a date to JSON format

[JSON](http://json.org) has no format for dates. That string you frequently see is a popular *convention*, nothing more. (And like many conventions, there are variations on that theme.)

Looking at it, it's the underlying Epoch value plus the timezone offset. Both of those pieces of information are available from the `Date` object. The Epoch value comes from `getTime`, and the timezone offset from `getTimezoneOffset` (which is in minutes).

Using those, you can create a string in that form.

Answer (score 0):

what about this,

I have Edited the code... pls try this,

```
public class DateHandler : IHttpHandler  
{  

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)  
    {  
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";  
        string action = context.Request.QueryString["jsonmode"];  
        string json = null;  

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(action) && action == ".net")  
        {  
            // Creates date in .NET date format "\/Date(14123123132)\/"  
            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();  
            json = ser.Serialize(DateTime.Now);  
        }  
        else  
            // iso format: "2010-08-31T01:35:05.785Z"  
            json = "\"" + DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("s") +   
                   "Z" + "\"";  

        context.Response.Write(json);   
    }  

    public bool IsReusable  
    {  
        get { return false; }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Delphian for your response. I wanted the other way around, the normal date string should be converted to json format something like this "\/Date(928129800000+0530)\/"

Comment: I have a suggestion, if your date value is javascript, you can convert that value to JSON using JSON.stringify Function

Answer (score 0):

Try the following simple method

var dateString= "/Date(1224043200000)/";
var date= new Date(parseInt(dateString.substr(6)));